# Achieving zero torque from DC motor

Tags: dc-motor, torque

The current project I am working on requires a motor to provide ~2 Nm to a spinning shaft and then upon command provide ~0 Nm, hence acting like a bearing. The motor will have an attached encoder, and the motor speed will be relatively low at 60-100 rpm.

Achieving approximately zero torque is made challenging due to non-zero cogging torque from the motor (~0.1 Nm). Would it be possible to compensate for the cogging torque by providing a current that generates a torque acting in the opposite direction of the cogging torque? For performance, ideally a torque less than 0.01 Nm would be produced by the motor.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Thank you all for the suggestions!

Comment: What kind of motor? Sounds like cogging or ripple torque compensation which I don't think is very different whether or not the motor is coasting. Once you get it working it could probably be left running all the time and improve your 2N-m output as well. I am not sure if an encoder is strictly necessary but it will help your investigation. But if you want to individually calibrate each pole it will be otherwise you will be limited to the single best fit for all poles. https://discourse.odriverobotics.com/t/anti-cogging-feature/293/2 Plenty of papers too: https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/10/1/96

Comment: http://www.roboticsproceedings.org/rss10/p42.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the comment, and no motor selections have been made as of yet. In the attached forum on ODrive - the measured holding torque at each encoder position will be the feedforward torque required to minimize cogging?

Comment: I didn't read through all of it but I think so. It would be the simplest place to start: map it out and regurgitate the opposite torque based on position. Feedback would be more complicated and I don't know if it reacts fast enough. Too bad you probably can't just put a torque sensor during normal operation on and always try to keep it locked on 0N-m or 2N-m due to expense (unless you already have one but I don't think you would be asking if you did).

Comment: Yeah - unfortunately a torque sensor is not feasible for this project. I'll check out ODrive's documentation for their anti-cogging feature a bit more. Thank you

Comment: What about a small disengagement mechanism acting like a clutch?

Comment: Hello Andy, thank you for the suggestion. Are you referring to an electric clutch? Also to be a bit more specific: I'm trying to create an active three axis gimbal with continuous rotation. I was thinking about using an electric clutch - but this would add to the number of circuits in the slip rings (hence increasing cost) as well as adding to the weight of the gimbal rings. Small supplementary torques (~0.1Nm) are also required intermittently to account for frictional losses and sustain rotation, which may still be messed with due to cogging with an electric clutch.

Comment: You can buy a brushless motor (often with a skewed stator) that will have zero cogging torque.

Comment: Some "Coreless" and "Slotles" motors do not have a cogging torque cause by internal magnetic coupling.

Comment: Instead of trying to work around a problematic solution, switch to a solution that doesn't have that problem in the first place: replace your brushed DC motor with any brushless motor (BLDC, induction, etc.).

Comment: @DavideAndrea Not any. Brushless motors can still have cogging.

Comment: Would you consider -10Nm to be less than 0.01Nm?

Answer (score 0):

Cogging as a problem inherent to almast all permanent magnet motors.

Your best bet for a non-cogging DC motor is either a universal motor
(either serial or parallel) if you want a brush-commutated motor, or a variable reluctance motor if you want a stepper motor.

A third option is to use an induction motor with a variable frequency drive.

getting zero torque from a PMDC motor by using torque reedback is possible if you can find a good way to mount a torque sensor and can drive the motor with sufficient speed and precision.

Answer (score 0):

A 10:1 reduction via a position sensor sounds plausible, but I would think it would be easier to use a slotless BLDC motor.